# Show/hide div on click with change class on current item clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying show/hide submenu items using click, sometimes it's working but sometimes it's opening/closing together specially open this in mobile (iOS devices)

The only condition is the click event firing in specific window size

Here is the code, not sure what's wrong here, its just doing slidetoggle and toggleClass to show/hide different icon and I wanted to open each menu at once

```js
$(".title").click(function(e) {
  var ww = $(window).width();
  if (ww < 992) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var linkItems = $(this);
    linkItems.toggleClass('title-mob-minus');
    linkItems.siblings().slideToggle();
  }
});
```

```css
.title {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.title-mob-minus {
  position:relative;
}
.title-mob-minus:after {
  content:"-";
  position:absolute;
  right:50%;
  color:#f00;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:bold;
 }
.link-list__items {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title" role="heading">
  <a href="javascript:;" role="link">Menu 1</a>
</div>
<div class="link-list__items">
  <ul role="menu">
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="test.html"><span>Submenu Item 1</span></a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="test.html"><span>Submenu Item 1</span></a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="test.html"><span>Submenu Item 1</span></a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="test.html"><span>Submenu Item 1</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="title" role="heading">
  <a href="javascript:;" role="link">Menu 2</a>
</div>
<div class="link-list__items">
  <ul role="menu">
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="test.html"><span>Submenu Item 1</span></a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="test.html"><span>Submenu Item 1</span></a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="test.html"><span>Submenu Item 1</span></a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="test.html"><span>Submenu Item 1</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You should use `class` as well as `role`

Comment: @zer00ne I already have class in `DIV` instead of anchor

Comment: Can you add style for the class `title-mob-minus` ?

Comment: @NimitShah I've updated the class and its being used to show the symbol (-) when opened